# how can java return false when comparing 2 numbers which has exactly the same type and value?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<br><% if (overLimit != null) {%><%=overLimitItemNO.getClass().equals(shoppingVO.getItem_no().getClass())%><%}%>
<br><% if (overLimit != null) {%><%=overLimitItemNO.getClass()%> vs <%=shoppingVO.getItem_no().getClass()%><%}%>
<br><% if (overLimit != null) {%><%=overLimitItemNO%> vs <%=shoppingVO.getItem_no()%><%}%> 
<br><% if (overLimit != null) {%><%=overLimitItemNO == shoppingVO.getItem_no()%><%}%>
```

and it shows the following on the browser

```
true 

class java.lang.Integer vs class java.lang.Integer 

300008 vs 300008 

false
```

Comment: When using an `Integer`, you **need** to use the `.equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use obj1.equals(obj2). == on objects only compares whether the two are the same exact instance

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals when comparing Integer's otherwise you are comparing object refs.